# Hadoop - MultipleInputs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am trying to use MultipleInputs from Hadoop. All my mapper will be FixedLengthInputFormat.

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, 
                    new Path(rootDir),       
                    FixedLengthInputFormat.class, 
                    OneToManyMapper.class);
```

The problem is that each mapper has fixed record width with different size.

> config.setInt(FixedLengthInputFormat.FIXED_RECORD_LENGTH, ??);

Is there anyway to passe the FIXED_RECORD_LENGTH for each mapper, using MultipleInputs?

Thanks!

Comment: I will try to override some method to give this behavior... If i have success, i will post here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public class CustomFixedLengthInputFormat extends FixedLengthInputFormat{

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, BytesWritable> createRecordReader(
            InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        //here i can control de recordLength size!
        int recordLength = ??;// getRecordLength(context.getConfiguration());
        if (recordLength <= 0) {
            throw new IOException(
                    "Fixed record length "
                            + recordLength
                            + " is invalid.  It should be set to a value greater than zero");
        }

        System.out.println("Record Length: " + recordLength);

        return new FixedLengthRecordReader(recordLength);
    }

}
```

Comment: So you are creating two of your customfixedlength record reader and setting it for each path?

Comment: Yes. The haoop framework is responsable for call  the "createRecordReader". I just set the record length.